# How can I convert a DMG to ISO on Mac OS X (preferably for free)?

Tags: macos, file-conversion, dmg, iso

I have medical records within Windows software within a DMG disk image. How can I convert the DMG to an ISO format on Mac OS X? Is it possible to do it within Disk Utility or CLI easily, or do I need an external utility?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use `hdiutil` to convert from `.dmg` to `.iso` directly:

```
$ hdiutil makehybrid -iso -joliet -o [filename].iso [filename].dmg
```

**Renaming `.cdr` to `.iso` is bad advice!** An `.iso` has a slightly different format that allows PC users to play the DVD as well. A renamed file will work on macOS, but NOT on a PC.

If you have a `.cdr` and want to convert it to an `.iso`, execute:

```
$ hdiutil makehybrid -iso -joliet -o [filename].iso [filename].cdr
```

Comment: Or you can just use the `.dmg` directly as input instead of going through `.cdr`.

Comment: yes, sure ;-) But please no renaming...

Comment: What would be the command to convert a dmg directly to iso just for completion sake of the question?

Comment: Does it work for creating a bootable Mac OS installtion iso image for VMWare?

Comment: For anyone getting the error `hdiutil: makehybrid: attach of disk image failed: 16`, you need to unmount the image first (using Disk Utility).

Comment: If you get `Segmentation fault: 11`, try prepending `sudo`.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, Disk Utility can do this. Use `Convert` then select your `dmg` file. In the `Save As` dialog that follows, select `DVD/CD master`. Disk Utility will insist on saving the new ISO as a `.cdr` file, but it is really an ISO. You can rename it to `.iso` in the Finder, if you like.

At http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/18/convert-dmg-to-cdr-or-iso-with-disk-utility/ there are screen shots that walk through this process.

Comment: "it is really an ISO" is plain wrong. Seeing a .cdr from OSX, there appears to be no difference to a .iso . But you feel it after your DVD does not work on Windows.

Comment: I am still unhappy with the accepted answer. Both Sean and mblakele failed here, because an answer was accepted, that was only right for OSX users. But this will strike back, as soon as you try to use a renamed .iso in Windows. I think correctness is important, because wrong information should not be kept in the public, even if it's "just windows" ;-)

Comment: This is still wrong, today. What a shame!

Comment: @mblakele    What convert button?  Not seeing that on Disk Utility (version 16.0) . Am I doing this wrong, or is this answer just obsolete because of other software changes?

Comment: @zipzit Apple likes to move things around from time to time. Try the `Images` menu, then `Convert...`

Answer (score 2):

Would be the same:

```
hdiutil makehybrid -iso -joliet -o [filename].iso [filename].dmg
```

For example:

```
hdiutil makehybrid -iso -joliet -o output_file.iso file_to_convert.dmg
```

Comment: Does it work for creating a bootable Mac OS installtion iso image for VMWare?

Answer (score -3):

You must mount the cdr people.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Unfortunately, this doesn't look like an attempt to answer the question.