# How to convert an .iso file to .dmg in terminal?

Tags: macos, dmg, iso

I want to convert an `.iso` to `.dmg`, how can I do this from Terminal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating A Bootable USB Of Windows 8.1 On OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103874/creating-a-bootable-usb-of-windows-8-1-on-os-x)

Comment: It's the same question and same answer just yours is more general in scope.  There is also this question:  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73183/copying-iso-file-to-usb-drive-in-os-x

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94330/how-can-i-convert-a-dmg-to-iso-on-mac-os-x-preferably-for-free

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OS X has `hdiutil`, a command line tool for making, manipulating and using disk images with an option to convert between different types of images.[1](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html)

To do this use the command with verb `convert` and option `-format`.

Option `-o` is used to specify the path and name of the output file.

There are several [formats](http://ss64.com/osx/hdiutil.html) available from which I post two for .DMG and one for .ISO:

```
  UDRW - UDIF read/write image
  UDRO - UDIF read-only image
  UDTO - DVD/CD-R master for export
```

Use the first one for a read/write-able .DMG. The resulting command is:

```
hdiutil convert /path/file.iso -format UDRW -o /path/file.dmg
```

The backward conversion would be done by

```
hdiutil convert /path/file.dmg -format UDTO -o /path/file.iso
```

Comment: Here's a nice use case for the opposite direction - Mac installers are DMG and some software wants an ISO (VMware / Parallels / etc...) - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/278336/generalizable-gude-to-convert-dmg-to-iso-bootable-for-lion-to-sierra